# Javascript - add class on hover and keep it until hover on another element

Tags: javascript, css, display

I'm trying to add a class to a div on hover but I need it to stay active until mouse enters a sibling.

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Hover me 1</p>
    <div class="hidden">Somthing 1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Hover me 2</p>
    <div class="hidden">Somthing 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Hover me 3</p>
    <div class="hidden">Somthing 3</div>
</div>
```

By default the div will have the class "hidden" and when the user hovers that div should display and stays visible until the user hover another div with the same class.

```
        .hidden {
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: visibility 0s 9999s, opacity 0.1s linear;
          }
        .show {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            transition-delay: 0s;
          }
```

This is what I'm trying to do

```
document.ready(function() {
    document.getElementByClassName("hidden").mouseenter(function() {
        document.getElementByClassName("show").classList.remove("show").classList.add("hidden");
        this.classList.remove("hidden").classList.add("show");
    });
});
```

It think this is easier to do with jQuery but I need to use pure JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `mouseenter` event listener to all elements with the `container` class that adds the `hidden` class to the `div` in each one and adds the `show` class to the `div` in the current one.

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');

containers.forEach(f => f.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  containers.forEach(e => {
    var div = e.querySelector('div');
    div.classList.add('hidden');
    div.classList.remove('show');
  })
  this.querySelector('div').classList.add('show')
}))
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 9999s, opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>Hover me 1</p>
  <div class="hidden">Somthing 1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Hover me 2</p>
  <div class="hidden">Somthing 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Hover me 3</p>
  <div class="hidden">Somthing 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should convert the NodeList to an Array as forEach is not supported everywhere for NodeLists `[...containers].forEach`

Answer (score 4):

**Pure CSS solution**

What you need is a `:hover` [CSS pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) and [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 9999s, opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.container p:hover + div.hidden {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Hover me 1</p>
    <div class="hidden">Somthing 1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Hover me 2</p>
    <div class="hidden">Somthing 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Hover me 3</p>
    <div class="hidden">Somthing 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not cover the use case OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this sort of thing with one listener. Here we check if the mouse is over a `.container p`, we store the last `hidden` div in a variable. If there is something in `element`, we add the `hidden` class back, then we remove the `hidden` class from the current sibling and store it in the `element` variable.

```js
let element;
document.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('.container p')) {
    if (element != null) {
      element.classList.add('hidden');
    }
    element = e.target.nextElementSibling;
    element.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 9999s, opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.container p {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Hover me 1</p>
  <div class="hidden">Somthing 1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Hover me 2</p>
  <div class="hidden">Somthing 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Hover me 3</p>
  <div class="hidden">Somthing 3</div>
</div>
```

I also added a `cursor: pointer` css rule on the `p` tags.